# How to retrieve nearby markers posted by other users (with Entities/Endpoints)?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-app-engine

I'm sorry the question is poorly worded. What I want to do is a bit complex so trying to put it into a question was hard.

I'm trying to find a way to load/retrieve nearby markers, posted by other users, onto a GoogleMap. So from your current location, in a 50 km radius (let's say) you can see markers that other users have posted, and you can tap them and what not.

I've figured out how to store a marker (latitude and longitude, along with a username) into an Entity. But I'm not sure how to retrieve nearby markers and load them on the map. I did a lot of reading on Google Cloud Endpoints API and I found some information on Geospatial Queries where you can use really simple tools to filter out entities (using GeoPts) that are beyond your radius. But there's a notification at the top of the page saying:

> This is an Alpha release of Geospatial search for datastore. It is not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy and may be subject to backward-incompatible changes. It is not recommended for production use. Access to this feature is available only to whitelisted applications; currently we are not accepting whitelist requests for this feature.

So I don't want to use it. I'm also trying to find something (a service) that's stable that can help me with this sort of application.

Your answers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until geospatial queries become GA you can use the App Engine Search API, which supports GeoPoint fields and geospatial queries: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/

The downside is you need to store a Document for each of your searchable entities.  In this document, you have a GeoPoint field that matches the corresponding entity's GeoPt value.  You might want to use the entity's ID as the Document's ID, or you could store it in an Atom field.

You can then send your geospatial query to the Search API which will return the matching Documents.  For each result, you can get the Document ID or the Atom field which contains the corresponding entity ID.  Once you have a list of entity IDs, you can do a batch get-by-key on Datastore, giving you the entities to return to your client.

It's not ideal, but (from experience) it does work.

I would suggest implementing your solution so that, if you need to, you can switch over to 'native' geospatial queries when they're supported in Datastore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there anyway I can reach you by message? Every now and then I have quick questions to ask about Endpoints but I rarely find an answer.